# How can I typecheck custom datatypes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to haskell, so sorry in advance.

I'm writing a program thats has a custom type "Rank". (The rank of a blackjack-card)

```
data Rank = Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade

data Card = Card Rank Suit


getCardValue :: Card -> Int
getCardValue (Card val _) = valueOfRank val

valueOfRank :: Rank -> Int
valueOfRank (Int i) = i --Doesnt work
valueOfRank Jack = 10
valueOfRank Queen = 10
valueOfRank King = 10
valueOfRank Ace = 11
```

Now I want to receive the respective value of a card with a function, my problem is, that I dont know how to typecheck if the value is of the type Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data Rank = Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
```

The above `Int` is a data constructor name, and is completely unrelated to the `Int` type. Indeed, `Jack` is a similar data constructor but there's no `Jack` *type* around.

If you want a `Rank` value actually containing a value of type `Int`, you need to use something like

```
data Rank = I Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
```

Here `I` is the constructor name (you can rename it as you wish), and `Int` now refers to the *type*. You can then use `Rank` as:

```
valueOfRank :: Rank -> Int
valueOfRank (I i) = i
valueOfRank Jack = 10
valueOfRank Queen = 10
valueOfRank King = 10
valueOfRank Ace = 11
```

Note that nothing prevents the programmer to abuse the `I` constructor and create invalid card values like `I 123`, `I 11`, and `I 1`.